# PhpStorm cannot connect to FTP server

Tags: phpstorm

I am currently using PhpStorm 2017.3.6. Mac pro version. I have been trying to connect to the FTP but it is not working. I keep getting this error message:

> "Could not login on FTP server".

I am 100% sure that I didn't make mistake with password or user name. It has not been up to 48 hours since I install the application on my Mac pro. Spent almost 6 hours trying to make it connect. When I got frustrated, I stopped and took a break of about 2 hours. Came back and noticed it has started working.

After I restarted my system, the whole issue started again. Cannot connect. I have tried using the "Passive Mode" and also "Always use the List Command" but none of them work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I once had this, I had a hosting provider where I could make extra FTP accounts, that ones worked. The problem in my case was that the FTP account I tried connecting with didn't give certain programs like phpstorm the access to add and delete files I think.

Comment: What authentication method is used? Please attach a screenshot of your (s)FTP connection setings.